# Cannot resolve method accept for JSQLParser

Tags: java, methods, jsqlparser

For `condition.accept` I get the error "cannot resolve method 'accept(cs4321.project2.Operators.SelectExpressionVisitor)". I'm not sure why because I'm following the [Expression `accept` method](http://jsqlparser.sourceforge.net/docs/net/sf/jsqlparser/expression/Expression.html) syntax correctly.

```
public class SelectExpressionVisitor implements ExpressionVisitor {
private Tuple tuple;
private Map<String, Integer> colToTupleIndexMap;
private boolean tupleFollowsCondition;

public SelectExpressionVisitor(Tuple tuple) {
    this.tuple = tuple;
    colToTupleIndexMap = DatabaseCatalog.getInstance()
            .colToTupleIndexMap;
    tupleFollowsCondition = false;
}

public Tuple getSelectTuple(Expression condition) {
    condition.accept(this);
    if(tupleFollowsCondition) {
        return tuple;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I imported the wrong Expression class, which didn't have an accept method.

**Correct import statement**

```
import net.sf.jsqlparser.expression.Expression;
```